# customizing transformer in spring integration

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

My TCP Server based on spring integration is working great.

It also handles reply-timeout at the server if the service takes long. When the service takes longer than reply-timeout set in  it will send the message to error channel and that in turn sends back error message to the client.

Here is my code:

```
<int:transformer id="errorHandler"
    input-channel="errorChannel"
    ref="myTransformer" method="transform" />
<bean id="myTransformer" class="com.sample.MyTransformer" />

public class MyTransformer {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyTransformer.class);

    public String transform(org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException e) {
        logger.error("timeout exception is thrown");
        return "Error in processing request.";
    }
}
```

The above code works and the client gets 'Error in processing request' and the server log has the entry 'timeout exception is thrown'. But I also see the following exception in the log:

```
2016-06-30 16:25:27,827 ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Implementation of MyTransformer does not seem to be correct.

Can you please help on how to customize transformer?
How to get the payload in the transform method so that I can reply to client as 'Error in processing request. payload = ' + payload?

Thanks

UPDATE: To avoid logging ReplyRequiredException, I changed the error-channel on tcp-inbound-gateway as follows:

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
    connection-factory="crLfServer"
    request-channel="requestChannel"
    error-channel="tcpErrorChannel"
    reply-timeout="10000"
    />
<int:channel id="tcpErrorChannel" /> 

<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel" ref="gateway" requires-reply="true"/>
<int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="timeoutChannel" default-reply-timeout="10000" />
<int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
    input-channel="timeoutChannel"
    output-channel="serviceChannel"/>

<int:channel id="timeoutChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="timeoutExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="timeoutExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="50" />
</bean>
```

But I am getting MessageDeliveryException. tcpErrorChannel setup seems to be wrong. Can you please suggest? Here is the Stacktrace:

```
2016-07-05 12:17:34,266 ERROR [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection] Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[67], headers={timestamp=1467735444239, id=30eb099e-955d-1bd3-1789-49aa9fc84b6f, ip_tcp_remotePort=64055, ip_address=127.0.0.1, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:64055:5678:908d39a1-d027-4753-b144-59b9c0390fd7}]
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred in error-handling flow; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@4876db09.tcpErrorChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:452)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@4876db09.tcpErrorChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:449)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    ... 14 more
```

The above exception will go away by changing errorChennel to tcpErrorChannel in :

Thanks a lot to Artem for his perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is continue of your other question [reply-timeout meaning in tcp-inbound-gateway in spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978738/reply-timeout-meaning-in-tcp-inbound-gateway-in-spring-integration).

Well, `ReplyRequiredException` is as result of the `<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel" ref="gateway" requires-reply="true"/>`.

`requires-reply="true"` - please, read its description. You can play with that though and make it as `false` (default one), but then your logic for "timeout" won't work. So, you don't have choice unless continue to live with that:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException
```

Although, that is just affect of one of subscribers for the default `errorChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler.

Now regarding your last question. All the exception are wrapped into `ErrorMessage` and sent into that `errorChannel`. Typically exceptions are wrapped into `MessagingException`, e.g. in this our case it is like:

```
else if (this.requiresReply && !isAsync()) {
    throw new ReplyRequiredException(message, "No reply produced by handler '" +
            getComponentName() + "', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.");
}
```

Pay attention into that `message` ctor argument it is exactly a `requestMessage` which is without reply in our scenario. And you can extract a desired `payload` from it.

So, now you can get `failedMessage` from the `ReplyRequiredException` in your `transform()` and extract its `payload` for your goal.

**UPDATE**

> Since this `ReplyRequiredException` is a known exception, there is no need to see it as Error.

Well, even it is a known exception, but it is an important one in other components and scenarios when it may not be appropriate do not receive a reply. The `ReplyRequiredException` is very common through the Framework components, so moving it to different category could be a big architectural error for your application.

To avoid those logs you just should not use a default `errorChannel`, but some other one from your TCP Inbound Gateway. Something like `error-channel="tcpErrorChannel"` and that's all. A default `errorChannel` will still have that `LoggingHandler` as a subscriber, but you already won't send error messages to that channel.

Comment: Regarding my first question, we log error exceptions and monitor them. Since this ReplyRequiredException is a known exception, there is no need to see it as Error. is there any way to avoid logging ReplyRequiredException as Error exception ?

I could like the following but may miss some other important exceptions. Can you please suggest any other ideas?
 <logger name="org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException">
  <level value="fatal" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
 </logger>

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Artem, Please see UPDATE in my question. Thanks.

Comment: That's true. Because you have missed to fix your `<int:transformer id="errorHandler"` to listen on that new `tcpErrorChannel`

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem. Thats perfect solution.