# TcpInboundGateway Server Configuration- on timeout a custom message to be sent

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration with Spring Boot. I have a TCP server with TcpInboundGateway setup and a Transformer that contains the business logic and it returns String on completion of Processing. This setup works fine when I receive the messages over the socket.

```
@Bean
public TcpInboundGateway paWebserviceInGate() {
    TcpInboundGateway inGateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
    inGateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory.serverConnectionFactory(port));
    inGateway.setRequestChannelName("paWebserviceInputChannel");
    inGateway.setReplyTimeout(5000);//To configure the timeout - but it does not work 
    return inGateway;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "paWebserviceInputChannel")
public String consume(byte[] bytes) {
    String message = new String(bytes);
    return paMessageHandler.processPAIndiators(message);
}
```

ConnectionFactory.java:

```
public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory(int port) {
    final AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
    connectionFactory.setSerializer(customDeserializer);
    connectionFactory.setDeserializer(customDeserializer);
    connectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(false);
    // connectionFactory.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Now, I have a requirement that on timeout of say 5 seconds, I need to send a custom message to the client. Let's say if the service takes 10 seconds, I need to send the custom message after 5 seconds to intimate the client about the timeout. (Please note, I don't have control over the client; so I cannot add timeout on client side).

I have used setReplyTimeout on the TcpInboundGateway; but it does not timeout after 5 sec.

I referred this post [reply-timeout meaning in tcp-inbound-gateway in spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978738/reply-timeout-meaning-in-tcp-inbound-gateway-in-spring-integration).

This post explains the xml configuration suggested by Artem Bilan. 
Can anyone please help with Java configuration? I am confused while Configuring my above code to include timeout. Should I use IntegrationFlows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into the framework to do that; I opened a [New Feature issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3107).

The timer for the reply only starts when the thread returns to the gateway; it only applies when processing asynchronously; you would have to process your request on a different thread. But that still won't help because the gateway just releases the thread after a reply timeout.

With the current state you will have to do it yourself in your service.

- enqueue to work to a task executor and wait for the reply
- if no reply received return your error condition

**NOTE** Once you reply to the gateway, you can not then send the real reply.